# ¿Cómo leer fecha de un fichero de texto y compararlo con la fecha actual?

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, txt

Quiero leer una fecha guardada en un documento de texto con el formato "2020/06/02", compararla con la fecha actual, y si está bien, no hacer nada, pero si pasan dos días de la fecha del fichero, añadir una línea debajo con un número incremental (1, 2, 3, 4...).

Esto es lo que tengo por ahora.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date

# Se genera fichero fecha 1
file = open("xxx\\1.txt", "w")

# Variable de fecha de hoy
today = date.today()

# Se genera fecha 1 con la fecha de hoy
file.write(str(date.today()) + "\n")
file.close()
```

Comment: EL fichero solo contiene una fecha en la primera línea con el formato que puse, y en la segunda linea habrá un contador. Si e vuelve a ejectuar y la fecha actual pasa de dos días de la fecha del fichero, el contador se incrementa en uno, y la fecha del fichero se actualiza con la actual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obtener la diferencia en días entre dos fechas basta con algo como:

```
(datetime.datetime.now() - fecha).days
#|______________________________|
#        datetime.timedelta
```

dónde fecha es un objeto `datetime.datetime` o `datetime.date`. Para obtener la fecha a partir de la cadena basta con usar `datetime.datetime.strptime` y `datetime.ddatetime.strftime` para el proceso inverso, el formato en éste caso es `"%Y/%m/%d"`.

El resto es simplemente trabajo con archivos:

```
from datetime import datetime, date


RUTA = "1.txt"

with open(RUTA, "a+") as fichero_fecha:
    fecha_actual = datetime.now()
    if fichero_fecha.tell():
        fichero_fecha.seek(0)
        fecha = datetime.strptime(next(fichero_fecha).rstrip(), "%Y/%m/%d")
        cont = int(next(fichero_fecha).split(".")[0])
        if (fecha_actual - fecha).days > 2:
            fichero_fecha.seek(0)
            fichero_fecha.truncate()
            fichero_fecha.write(f'{fecha_actual.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")}\n{cont + 1}.txt\n')
    else:
        fichero_fecha.write(f'{fecha_actual.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")}\n1.txt\n')
```

El formato del archivo es siempre de la forma:

> ```
> 2020/06/02
> <numero>.txt
> ```

- Si el archivo no existe o está vacío se crea y se asigna como primera fila la fecha actual y como segunda un 0.
- Si existe se asume que es válido y tiene ya ambas filas con el formato explicado. Si la fecha difiere en dos días de la actual la actualiza e incrementa en uno el contador de la segunda linea, si no difiere dos días no hace nada.

---

Si se quiere que también el nombre del fichero cambie de acuerdo al contador, sin modificar la lógica anterior podemos hacer algo como:

```
from datetime import datetime, date
import pathlib


RUTA = ("./date/")

fecha_actual = datetime.now()

path_dir = pathlib.Path(RUTA)
path_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
files = tuple(path_dir.rglob("[0-9]*.txt"))

if len(files) > 1:
    raise RuntimeError("Varios archivos del directorio cumplen con el patrón")
elif not files:
    with open(path_dir / "1.txt", "a+") as fichero_fecha:
        fichero_fecha.write(f'{fecha_actual.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")}\n1.txt\n')
else:
    path_file = pathlib.Path(files[0])
    rename = False
    with open(path_file, "a+") as fichero_fecha:
        fichero_fecha.seek(0)
        fecha = datetime.strptime(next(fichero_fecha).rstrip(), "%Y/%m/%d")
        cont = int(next(fichero_fecha).split(".")[0])
        if (fecha_actual - fecha).days > 2:
            fichero_fecha.seek(0)
            fichero_fecha.truncate()
            fichero_fecha.write(f'{fecha_actual.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")}\n{cont + 1}.txt\n')
            rename = True
    if rename:
        path_file.rename(path_dir / f"{cont + 1}.txt")
```

Solo puede haber un fichero de la forma {numero_entero}.txt en el directorio, si hay varios (p.ej `[1.txt, 3.txt]`) se lanza una excepción. Se podría manejar ésto también, pero hay que resolver varios conflictos, el más obvio ¿si al renombrar hay otro archivo con el mismo nombre y cuya fecha no requiere actualización que hacemos?

Si el fichero o el directorio no existen se crean, el fichero con nombre `1.txt` y el contenido inicial descrito.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, todo perfecto.

Comment: Lo único, para que empiece en 1 en vez de 0? Y que tras el contador quede algo tipo: "1.txt".

Comment: Para que empiece en uno el contador simplemente cambiar `fichero_fecha.write('0\n')` por `fichero_fecha.write('1\n')`. En cuanto a lo segundo, ¿quieres cambiar también el nombre del archivo y no solo la linea?

Comment: Exactamente donde? Es como lo intenté hacer pero no me funcionó correctamente. Solamente la línea dentro del fichero.

Comment: El nombre del fichero no se cambia, no deduje ésto de la pregunta, no obstante si quieres que eso suceda, sin cambiar la implementación actual se puede hacer con unas cuantas lineas más.

Comment: Vale ya está con el 1.Lo intenté añadiendo un str con la extensión al final. Y a la hora de crearlo no da problemas, pero si cuando el fichero existe, ya que genera el error invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.txt'.

Comment: En realidad solo es para cambiar lo que está dentro del fichero, no la extensión del mismo (puede que no me haya explicado bien). El incremental seria 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt, etc.

Comment: A vale, entonces es solo modificar el formateo de cadenas y usar str.split por ejemplo para parsear el contador. He editado de nuevo, he modificado ambos códigos, dejando la segunda versión que modifica también el nombre del fichero, por si a alguien le interesa en el futuro, ya que está.

Comment: Perfecto @FJSevilla!